# MS excel: expressions automatic read value from a cell?

Tags: excel, automation, cell, vba

I hope to explain what I need in the right way.

I have to work with a huge number of data.
Those dataset are ordered in the same way and I need to take the same info from all.

The problem is that I am not able to set the cell in the formulas without editing all the formulas.

In the picture you can see that the dataset start at the line **74** and it involved **7** lines total

the formula is easy: =max(79:85) but I am not able to find an automatic way to set the interval.
The first item is the line "(start_dataset_line+5)" and the last one is "(first_item_line+total_numer_line)"
The formula shoud be =max(C$**"valueinthecellB74+5"**:C$**"valueinthecellB74+5+valueinthecellC74"**)

but I do not know how to write the non fixed bold expression

Is it possible to set in automatically even with a macro?
Thanks

[image: example]

Comment: So, you want `95` in B95 and row count in C95?

Comment: I want that the formula like =(A1+letterA2_numberA3) sum the value in A1 and the value from a variable cell compose by the letter written in cell A2 (eg C) and the number written in cell A3 (eg 7). So in this case the formula is =(A1+C7), if I change the value in cell A2 (eg I set D) the formula will became =(A1+D7) without modify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the INDIRECT function to calculate the range.

In your case

```
=MAX(INDIRECT("C"&B74+5&":C"&B74+4+C74))
```

Buona fortuna con Excel :)

Answer (score 1):

This would do:

```
=MAX(OFFSET(C5;B74;0;C74;1))
```

Comment: The problem is not in the formula, but the linked interval. E.G. the next dataset start at line 95 so the interval it will be different. I have to link the "74" to the the value in the cell so the next dataset it will link value "95"